# Asimov's Foundation Editions

Tags: isaac-asimov, foundation, revision

I want to get into the Foundation Trilogy, and was going to purchase the Kindle editions from Amazon. But a reviewer brought to my attention that all the copies in print these days are of the "revised" edition. He quoted a couple places that didn't seem to alter that much, but I read another comment that mentioned entire conversations had been edited out.

Does anybody know what and how much content has been cut out of these novels since their original publication in book form? Is it enough to matter? What was the motive for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Wow, I've never heard of this.  Sad!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the revisions in each book are relatively minor, either tidying up small continuity errors, modernising language (transistors = tubes, computers =  calculators, etc) and removing spoilers that have occurred due to the publishing dates not lining up correctly. I've found a couple of [reviewers](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/barnes-noble-leatherbound-classics-the-foundation-trilogy-isaac-asimov/1106658785?ean=9780307292063) stating that some conversations have been removed from the second book but that seems to be the largest extent of the changes and wasn't noticed at the time of reading:

> There is content missing in Chapter 4 an entire conversation is
>   missing between three characters that play a huge part in what happens
>   in the following chapter. I originally did not know this until I went
>   back and fourth between the hardcover book and the digital version of
>   the book and realized that some chapter were edited

This seems a very small price to pay for readability.